# JSON String to AnalogValueObject using Bacpypes

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, bacnet

I am currently using a raspberry pi to process a device transmitting a JSON string and use Bacpypes to transmit the data over Bacnet IP.  I am having an issues breaking down the JSON string so that I can send the multiple data points as a Bacnet Analog Value Object. The JSON string is similar to:

{'sn':1, 'sampletime'123, 'device_1':{'p1':100,'p2':200}, 'device_2':{'p1':100,'p2':200}, 'temp': 50, 'hum': 23}

Right now I am able to pass the string to a list where I can access one data point at a time. This single data point is passed to all of the objects on our Bacnet system.

I am trying to figure out how to either break up this JSON string so that I can list each data point as it's own Bacnet object or pass the whole string through as a single object.

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Expected output is seeing each of the variables of the JSON string onto Bacnet (I am using BQT for this). As present value for each of the variables as an analog value object.